# Unable to understand the usage of std_msgs/Empty.h

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anybody understand what does the '--once' mean in 'rostopic pub toggle_led std_msgs/Empty'?

What should command should I put in the terminal to toggle the led of my choice. In my opinion, I think that '--once' is the cause of my failure.

Hope you guys can help me to solve this issue. THANKS!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65737/unable-to-understand-the-usage-of-std_msgs/empty.h/) by [Edward Ramsay](https://answers.ros.org/users/4814/edward-ramsay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out

```
rostopic pub -h
```

For an explanation of --once. It doesn't do what you think it does.

Then, you might want to read the [wiki documentation on msg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg), since it seems like you don't understand how you can use them. It might also help you to review the [publisher/subscriber](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber) tutorial.

As for your question: std_msgs/Empty is just that - a message without any associated data. If you want to select which LED to blink, you'll want another message type that includes at least one data field.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Replace Empty with Bool and in the callback change led_state to toggle_msg.  As lindzey said read up on the documentation.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-06-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2